# Como Bloquear un Programa de VB para que sea usado solo en un pc

Tags: vb.net, vb

Buenas esta es una simple pregunta de orientación amigos, tengo un sistema echo en **VB.net**, bien mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que este programa funcione **en un solo equipo** ? al momento de ser instalado solo funcione en dicho equipo y no pueda ser copiado o modificado. Logre ver en YouTube que con un serial de ser echo con serial se podría aplicar a un solo computador ?.

Comment: Funcionó con el serial?

Comment: Yo intente con el serial pero veo que cuando lo instalo en otra pc ese mismo serial funciona en otra pc, yo quiero es que un serial se único a un computador

Comment: Intentaste verificando con la Mac address del equipo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo aplico las licencias por la direccion MAC de la computadora, simplemente en el ejecutable agrego una linea de codigo o un modulo que al abrirlo verifique la dirección MAC si esta es la que asigno abre sin problema de lo contrario se bloquea.

```
Using mc As New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
   For Each mo As ManagementObject In mc.GetInstances()
       If mo("MacAddress").ToString() = "25:A4:AA" Then
         frminicio.show
       End If
   Next
```

End Using

Comment: Eso tambien esta muy bueno ! para aplicarlo voy a probar a ver que tal funciona amigo !. Gracias por tu ayuda se aprecia

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Lo de usar un serial sería lo más práctico.

Ejemplo sencillo para generar un serial:

1. Creas una aplicación que te servirá para crear tus claves seriales, partiendo del nombre de la máquina donde se va a instalar:

Función para crear una clave SHA. La usas así: CreaSHA(Environment.MachineName)

```
Public Function CreaSHA(Texto As String) As String
        Dim Enc As New Text.UTF8Encoding
        Dim Dat() As Byte = Enc.GetBytes(Texto)
        Dim _Re() As Byte = Nothing

        Dim Sha As New Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

        _Re = Sha.ComputeHash(Dat)

        Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder

        For i As Short = 0 To _Re.Length - 1
            If _Re(i) < 16 Then sb.Append("0")
            sb.Append(_Re(i).ToString("x"))
        Next

        Return sb.ToString.ToUpper
    End Function
```

Esto te creará una clave Hexadecimal de 40 caracteres de largo.
En tu aplicación, deberás ingresar la clave generada y este evaluará de la misma forma que sean iguales:

```
Dim ClaveSerial As String = "SerieIngresada"

        If CreaSHA(Environment.MachineName) <> ClaveSerial Then
            MessageBox.Show("Licencia inválida", "Cerrando Aplicación", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas Graciasya mediste una luz de como hacerle, intentare partir desde este punto. Estaba bloqueado no sabia ni por donde comenzar !!!

Comment: Estare avisando si logre conseguir hacer el programa